# Trying to do a HttpRequest to survey monkey and that returns <h1>Service Requires SSL</h1> because of redirection

Tags: java, httpclient, surveymonkey

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class SurveymonkeyTest2 {

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.setRedirectHandler(new DefaultRedirectHandler() {                
        @Override
        public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {


            boolean isRedirect = super.isRedirectRequested(response, context);

            if (!isRedirect) {
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();    
                if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return isRedirect;
        }
    });

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize");


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_type","code"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "XXXX"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization","Bearer " +"XXXYYXXZZ" ));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key","APIKey" ));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Running the above returns

## Service Requires SSL

because of redirect URI which is http://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize/. What should be the redirect_uri if I am running this as a standalone java application using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect to a URL owned by SurveyMonkey.  You must redirect to a URL which you control that can perform the next OAuth authorization step.  There is a long in-depth explanation of how OAuth is used by SurveyMonkey here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/guide_oauth

Comment: Hi Miles.. The guide says - Once a user authorizes your application to have access to their account, their browser will receive a 302 redirect which will send them to the OAuth redirect URI you configured for your application. 
I have set the redirect URI on my application (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/myapps) to http://localhost.

Even then, the HTTPResponse shows the redirect URI location to be ttp://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize/.

Comment: You control the redirect yourself via the query string parameter redirect_uri.  Just change the one you send to SurveyMonkey to localhost.  If it's valid SurveyMonkey will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth provides an opportunity for a user to authorize access to a web application in their web browser. You're emulating a browser which is neither the intended use nor is it permitted by SurveyMonkey's Terms of Use.

In order to request access to a user's SurveyMonkey account, you must present the user with SurveyMonkey's interface in a web browser. If you set your redirect URI to localhost as Miles suggested, you could capture the redirect in your application with a web service running in your application. Another option would be to build a web service available on the internet which would process the redirect and send the result to your local application. It's possible to add additional query parameters to your OAuth authorization URL which will be passed to the redirect URI allowing you to identify an instance.